# how to test component with fetch operation in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      isDone: false
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            firstName:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              placeholder="enter your first name"
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            lastName:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              placeholder="enter your last name"
              value={this.state.lastName}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
          </label>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  private handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;

    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }

  private handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ isDone: true });

    const nameMatch = () => {
      return !(this.state.firstName.match('^Cel.*') && this.state.firstName.endsWith('on'));
    };

    if (nameMatch()) {
      alert('Please enter a valid name');
      return;
    }

    if (!this.state.lastName.endsWith('on')) {
      alert('check lastname too');
      return;
    }
    this.getFullName();
  }

  private getFullName() {


    const params = {
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName
    };

    const urlendPoint = `https://github.com/`;

    // (urlendPoint as any).search = new URLSearchParams(params);

    fetch(urlendPoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => data)
      .catch(error => {
        alert('Please check the names and try again');
      });

   ...do something...
  }
}
```

as part of the unit testing, In react using Jest and enzyme, I have the following test case

```
it('should fetch data correctly', (done) => {
            fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify([]));
 let wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />).instance();
  expect(wrapper.state.fullName).toEqual([]);
});
```

Here I'm trying to mock the fetch operation and test the getfullName() function that has been defined.

On doing this, I get the error `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified 
by jest.setTimeout.`

I do not understand whats going wrong though. How should I mock the function such that I mock the fetch and test the function?

Comment: how do you mock `fetch` to be able later `fetch.mockResponseOnce`?

Comment: You do not call done callback

Comment: Either use async await in the block of the test, promises, or if you specify explicitly done, you must then call done otherwise the test will not stop

Comment: @quirimmo - my question is not that its not ending, my question is that when I run the above test, I don't cover the entire function. So how do I modify the test case such that I can cover the whole function?